# Box View Api, Extracting tables from SVG file in PHP

Tags: php, box

I am using Box view api in PHP to convert PDF to HTML. This returns SVG file, now how to identify the tables in SVG file returned by this api?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0):

An SVG is a vectorial image format. It does not contains information about tables, you should try an other approach.